# Array of image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, image

How to put into `Array` some source to WPF Controls called `Image`? O this forum i find, but how to make array?

```
BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage()
logo.BeginInit();
logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/img/3.jpg");
logo.EndInit();

tmpimage.Source = logo;
```

But i need sometring like this:

```
Image[] img = new Image[3];
img[0].Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/img/3.jpg");
tmpimage.Source = img[0];
```

Comment: what do you want to do - show a list of images ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Image[] images = new Image[3] { new Image(), new Image(), new Image() };
images[0].Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/img/3.jpg"));
images[1].Source = new BitmapImage... // etc...
```

Alternatively, make your image factory a function and use LINQ:

```
Image CreateBitmap(string uri)
{ 
    return new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri)) };
}

Image[] GetImages()
{
    var imageUris = new[]
    {
        "pack://application:,,,/img/3.jpg", 
        "pack://application:,,,/img/elephant.jpg", 
        "pack://application:,,,/img/banana.jpg"
    };
    return imageUris.Select(CreateBitmap).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) is not a base class of [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx). I guess you are confusing it with [ImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx).

Comment: And did you know that BitmapImage has a [constructor with a Uri parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602473.aspx)? That would save you all the BeginInit and EndInit stuff.

Comment: Ah really? I was just going off the original poster's code. I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Array of BitmapImage :

```
    BitmapImage[] iHab;

    BitmapImage CreateBitmap(string uri)
        { 
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri));
        }

    BitmapImage[] GetImages()
        {
        string currDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string[] imageUris;

        //Get directory path of myData 
        string temp = currDir + "\\Media\\hcia\\";
        imageUris = Directory.GetFiles(temp, "habitation*.png");
        return imageUris.Select(CreateBitmap).ToArray();  
        }

    private void Rec_hab_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        iHab = GetImages();
        pointer.Source = iHab[7]; // the 7th image : can be manipulated with an i++
    }
```